# Safari not displaying bootstrap dropdown menu correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, webkit, microsoft-edge

I'm using bootstrap and struggling to get Safari to display the dropdown menu correctly. It looks fine in Edge. Safari appears to be using default browser controls. Is there a way to override this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and show some code. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know why Safari does this but it can be overwritten by adding the following CSS.

```
select {-webkit-appearance:none;}
```

This works for me.